# mu4e adds sender with reply-all

Tags: mu4e

I use `mu4e`. When I reply-all to an email, my own email appears in CC. I have these lines in my configuration:

```
(setq mu4e-compose-dont-reply-to-self t)
(setq
 message-send-mail-function   'smtpmail-send-it
 user-mail-address "email@domain.com"
 ...
)
```

I don't have multiple accounts as in [this Github issue](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/512). The value of the variable `mu4e-user-mail-address-list` is my `username@hostname.domain.tld`, where `username` is my login name and `hostname.domain.tld` is the hostname of the computer.

When I click `Customize this variable`, I see that it was changed, but not by me:

```
INS DEL Address: username@hostname.domain.tld
INS
 State : CHANGED outside Customize.
```

How can I avoid my email when replying to all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old question, but since it is the first thing that pops up in google (at least for me), I guess it is worth updating.

The answer provided by @miguelmorin no longer works, see [the manual for Writing messages, C.4.9](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Writing-messages.html):

> You need list your personal addresses by passing one or more --my-address=... to mu init. Note that the mu4e-user-mail-address-list which was used in older mu4e versions is no longer used. Also see the entries for version 1.4 in NEWS.org (N) in the main-menu.

You now have to use `mu` to register your email address:

```bash
mu init --maildir=/path/to/mail/folder --my-address=example@example.com
```

After this, you can control the inclusion of your email address in CC while a reply-to-all configuring the `mu4e-compose-keep-self-cc` in `~/.emacs` (it defaults to `nil`).

If you have multiple email addresses, you need to include that many `--my-address=...` parameters, per [the documentation](https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Initializing-the-message-store.html):

```bash
mu init --maildir=~/Maildir --my-address=jim@example.com --my-address=bob@example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: This answer is for `mu4e` before version 1.4. See above for the solution with the more recent version.

It seems that `mu4e` does not pick up the email address from the `sendmail` settings. The variable `mu4e-user-mail-address-list` was changed outside of the initialisation file and one can override it with:

```
(setq mu4e-user-mail-address-list (quote ("email@domain.com")))
```

Evaluate the region or reload the file, and now `mu4e` no longer includes the email in reply-all. And when you reply to an email sent from one person  to you, it does not ask you whether to reply all or just to the sender.